# Webapplication automation on Browserstack

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cloud, bdd, browserstack, selenium-remotedriver

Webapplication automation on Browserstack -When we try to run WebApplication script with hardcoded URL > it runs successfully without any error on device Iphone 14 latest browser, same way when we are trying to read URL from configProperties - it is not picking up the tag based url or pick scenarios defined on feature file. Note-It is not an issue on desktop`your text`

Driver code with hardcoded Url

```java
public static RemoteWebDriver getBrowserStackDriver(Scenario scenario) throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    //Map<String,Object> bsCapabilities = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,String> bsCapabilities = new HashMap<>();
    caps.setCapability("browserName", "safari");
    caps.setCapability("device", "iPhone 14");
    caps.setCapability("realMobile", "true");
    caps.setCapability("os_version", "16");
    bsCapabilities.put("browserstack.idleTimeout", "90");
    bsCapabilities.put("browserstack.selenium_version", BasePage.setValue("bs_selenium_version"));
    bsCapabilities.put("browserstack.use_w3c", BasePage.setValue("browserstack_use_w3c"));
    caps.setCapability("name", scenario.getName());
    bsCapabilities.forEach(caps::setCapability);
    //bsCapabilities.put("device", BasePage.readConfig("chrome_emulation_device"));
    //bsCapabilities.put("device", BasePage.readConfig("environment"));
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Objects.requireNonNull(setURL())), caps);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    
    try {
        driver.get("https://www.flexa.nl");
        WebElement cookiepopUp=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']")));
        cookiepopUp.click();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        logger.fatal("Browserstack driver is not initialized");
        Assert.fail("ERROR: Browserstack driver is not initialized: " + e);
    }
    //quit the driver
    //driver.quit();
    return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Objects.requireNonNull(setURL())), caps);

    //return null;
}
```

Code inside setURL() for BS

```java
private static String setURL() {
    String url = "";
    if (endpoint.startsWith("saucelabs"))
        url = "http://" + BasePage.setValue("sauce_username") + ":" + BasePage.setValue("sauce_accesskey")
                + "@ondemand.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com/wd/hub";
    else if (endpoint.startsWith("browserstack"))
        url = "https://" + BasePage.setValue("browserstack_username") + ":" + BasePage.setValue(
                "browserstack_accesskey") + "@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub";
    return url;
}
```

**Scenarios in feature file**

@COATINGS_AUTOMOTIVE @Mobile_Smoke
Feature: Atomotive_EN

```
@Search
  Scenario: Verify search bar open-close
    Given The user navigates to homepage
    Then Homepage should be displayed
    When User clicks open search bar
    Then Search bar should be visible
    When User clicks close search bar
    Then Search bar should be invisible





@Search
  Scenario: Verify search suggestion container for Market segment
    Given The user navigates to homepage
   Then Homepage should be displayed
    When User clicks open search bar
    Then Search bar should be visible
    When User fills search input with Metal
    Then Suggestion container overlay should be visible for EWT-918
```

It has to run script automatically by picking scenario from feature file and Url from configProperties

**Note-Automation script runs on browserstack for Desktop without any issue**, but same not working for Mobile( it is not picking the url or scenario from feature file or ConfigProperties) not an issue if  I hardcode the URL

Also adding code which is working on windows 10 , chrome browser on mobile emulator

```
public static RemoteWebDriver getBrowserStackDriver(Scenario scenario) {
        try {
            setBrowserResolution();
            //DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            MutableCapabilities caps = new MutableCapabilities();
            Map<String, String> bsCapabilities = new HashMap<>();
            bsCapabilities.put("os", BasePage.setValue("bs_os"));
            bsCapabilities.put("os_version", BasePage.setValue("bs_os_version"));
            bsCapabilities.put("resolution", BasePage.setValue("bs_resolution"));
            bsCapabilities.put("browser", BasePage.setValue("bs_browser"));
            bsCapabilities.put("browser_version", BasePage.setValue("bs_browser_version"));
            bsCapabilities.put("browserstack.selenium_version", BasePage.setValue("bs_selenium_version"));
            bsCapabilities.put("name", scenario.getName());
            bsCapabilities.put("browserstack.use_w3c", BasePage.setValue("browserstack_use_w3c"));
            bsCapabilities.put("project", BasePage.setValue("bs_project_name"));
            bsCapabilities.put("build", BasePage.setValue("cucumber.filter.tags") + "_" + LocalDate.now());
            bsCapabilities.put("browserstack.idleTimeout", "90");
            if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
                ChromeOptions withExtension = chromeOptions();
                caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, withExtension);
            }
            if (endpoint.endsWith("mobile")) {
                ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
                mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", BasePage.readConfig("chrome_emulation_device"));
                chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
                caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
            }
            bsCapabilities.forEach(caps::setCapability);
            return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Objects.requireNonNull(setURL())), caps);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.fatal("Browserstack driver is not initialized");
            Assert.fail("ERROR: Browserstack driver is not initialized: " + e);
        }
        logger.fatal("Browserstack driver is NULL : ");
        return null;
    }
```

And ChromeOption code for driver-Chrome

```
private static ChromeOptions chromeOptions() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        if (endpoint.endsWith("mobile")) {
            Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
            mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", BasePage.readConfig("chrome_emulation_device"));
            chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
        }
        chromeOptions.setHeadless(Boolean.parseBoolean(BasePage.readConfig("headless")));
        chromeOptions.addExtensions(new File("src/test/resources/extension/extension.crx"));
        chromeOptions.setHeadless(Boolean.parseBoolean(BasePage.readConfig("headless")));
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*", "ignore-certificate-errors");
        return chromeOptions;
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the scenarios as plain text. Do not post images of code.